# Minimal trace norm on the set of matrices with fixed diagonal entries

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, normed-spaces, nuclear-norm

What is the minimal nuclear norm (sum of singular values) on all $n \times n$ matrices $A$  whose diagonal is fixed, i.e., $diag(A) = v$? Is it true that the diagonal matrix is a minimizer?

Comment: What is the *diagonal* of an $m\times n$ (non quadratic) matrix?

Comment: Thanks, I should assume a square matrix. Sorry about that. I will fix it.

Comment: what do you mean by $diag(A)=v$

Comment: I mean that the diagonal elements are fixed. $v$ is a fixed vector, and diag is function. diag of a matrix (in Matlab) returns a vector containing its diagonal elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nuclear norm is dual to the spectral norm $\| \cdot\|_2$:
$$
\|A\|_* = \max_{\|X\|_2 \le 1} \langle A, X \rangle
$$
Then since $\|\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{sign}(v))\|_2 \le 1$, any matrix $A$ which satisfies $\operatorname{diag}(A)=v$ must have:

$$  \|A\|_*\ge \langle A, \operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{sign}(v)) \rangle = \langle v, \operatorname{sign}(v) \rangle=\|v\|_1
$$
In particular, $\|\operatorname{diag}(v)\|_* = \|v\|_1$, so the diagonal matrix is a minimizer.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you so much.

Comment: So this shows that for a fixed diagonal matrix, the trace norm is not a good proxy for rank, because it is minimized when the rank is maximum (diagonal matrix). Am I right?

Comment: If only the diagonal is fixed, then no it's not. But you can solve that problem explicitly: $\operatorname{diag}(u)^{-1} v u^T$ is the set of minimal rank matrices with diagonal $v$.

Comment: I see. That is a  rank one matrix where all columns are equal.

Comment: How about a block diagonal matrix? Does this result generalize to that as well? I.e. does a block diagonal matrix have the lowest trace norm, among all matrices whose elements on the blocks are fixed and known, but their other elements (corresponding to the zero elements of the block diagonal matrix) are arbitrary?

Comment: Yes, a block diagonal matrix will have a svd with block diagonal unitary matrices, which can be used to form a dual certificate.